# How to copy values from an array and paste it in another sheet based on a condition?

Tags: excel, vba

In a sheet named "Import" I have an array of two columns which I have named "test123". In the first column I have a lot of unique IDs, while the second displays the conversation number (NR). The data can be illustrated like this:

```
 ID    NR
1234    1
2234    1
4556    2
8965    2
5556    2
6789    2
2221    3
2145    3
9876    3
```

Further, I have an array with conversation numbers I want to show in another sheet named "Output". E.g. I want to extract the IDs for conversation number 2. I want this code to paste these values in the sheet "Output" with the first value in F6.

Until now I am able to paste all values from the whole array. In cell B15 (in the "output" sheet) I have the name of the array. Had to do this since the array will change. In A20:A30 ("Output" sheet) I have the conversation numbers I want to show.

```
Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()

Dim xRng As Range
Dim xLastRow As Long
Dim xLastRow2 As Long
Dim i As Integer
On Error Resume Next

Set xRng = Worksheets("Import").Range(Range("B15"))
If xRng.Value = Worksheets("Output").Range("A20:230").Value Then
xRng.Copy Range("F6")
xLastRow = xRng.Rows.Count + 1
End If

End Sub
```

Do someone have any suggestions to this problem?

Comment: You could use a dictionary storing the conversation number as key, and storing each ID when the conversation name is repeated.

Comment: Check the IF statement, you have put 230 instead of A30

Comment: Thanks! but the code is still not working